# Problem faced using user-defined mod function in loop

Tags: function-construction, procedural-programming

I want to make a program which tell whether a number perfect or not.So i tried like that:

```
mod[x_, y_] := Module[{x0 = x, y0 = y, p, q},
  For[i = 1, i <= x0/y0, i++, p = i];
  q = x0 - (y0*p);
  q]

perfectc[n_] := Module[{n0 = n, s = 0},
  For[i = 1, i <= n0, i++, If[mod[n0, i] == 0, s = s + i]];
  If[s == 2*n0, Print[n0, " is a perfect number"], 
   Print[n0, " isn't a perfect number"]];
  ]
```

First I make mine `mod[]` function then use it in the `perfectc[]` function.But It's not working.Rather using my `mod[]` function if i use build-in `Mod[]` function the program run well.

```
perfectc[n_] := Module[{n0 = n, s = 0},
      For[i = 1, i <= n0, i++, If[Mod[n0, i] == 0, s = s + i]];
      If[s == 2*n0, Print[n0, " is a perfect number"], 
       Print[n0, " isn't a perfect number"]];
      ]
```

Can Anyone help me to figure out this. Any hints or solution will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do not insist on procedural code, then simply define perfectNumberQ[x_Integer] := (Plus @@ Most[Divisors[x]] === x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that your `mod` function increments the variable `i`. So you call `perfectc` which increments `i`, then it calls `mod` which also increments `i`. Try either using different incrementing variables for `mod` and `perfectc` or add them to the `Module` like this:

```
mod[x_, y_] := 
 Module[{x0 = x, y0 = y, p, q, i}, 
  For[i = 1, i <= x0/y0, i++, p = i];
  q = x0 - (y0*p);
  q]

perfectc[n_] := 
 Module[{n0 = n, s = 0, i}, 
  For[i = 1, i <= n0, i++, If[mod[n0, i] == 0, s = s + i]];
  If[s == 2*n0, Print[n0, " is a perfect number"], 
   Print[n0, " isn't a perfect number"]];]
```

Comment: Oops..why i miss it.Really embracing.But Thanks @MassDefect Sir.I will follow this.